# Can <sitemapindex> contain both <url> and <sitemap> items?

Tags: sitemap

Can I put both `<url>` and `<sitemap>` index inside my `<sitemapindex>`? I have a site example.com and my main sitemap stores here example.com/sitemap.xml and contains following:

```
<sitemapindex>
    <url>
        <loc>example.com/catalog</loc>
    </url>
    <sitemap>
        <loc>ny.example.com/sitemap.xml</loc>
    </sitemap>
    <sitemap>
        <loc>la.example.com/sitemap.xml</loc>
    </sitemap>
</sitemapindex>
```

So I have a few `<url>` (which are pages) and a lot of `<sitemap>` elements (which are sitemapindexes too).

How to organize that structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can't, because sitemapindex documents can only reference sitemap documents.

See here for more info: http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html#index